# Even after defining a function, the error occur and say function is not defined

Tags: javascript, function

In javaScript
After calling getSavedTodos()

Error occur,
Uncaught ReferenceError: getSavedTodos is not defined

error occur even after defining the function getSavedTodos()

I am using VS code

```
const todos = getSavedTodos()


const filters = {
    search: '',
    hideFalseStates: false
}


const getSavedTodos = function() {
    const todoJSON=localStorage.getItem('todo')
    if(todoJSON !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(todoJSON)
    }
}
```

don't know the occurrence of the error, is there something change in formate of the code?

Comment: Can't call it before it gets defined. If it was a *function declaration* instead it would get hoisted and would work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your errors are because you called the function before you defined it. The code is read top to bottom, so you cannot use any variable or function before you define it.

```
const todos = getSavedTodos() //<-- Move this to after you defined the function

const filters = {
    search: '',
    hideFalseStates: false
}


const getSavedTodos = function(){
    const todoJSON = localStorage.getItem('todo')
    if(todoJSON !== null) {
        return JSON.parse(todoJSON)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using it *before* you define it.

You have two options:

1. Just move your definition up to before you use it:

   ```
   const getSavedTodos=function(){
       const todoJSON=localStorage.getItem('todo')
       if(todoJSON!==null)
       {
           return JSON.parse(todoJSON)
       }
   }

   const todos = getSavedTodos()

   const filters={
       search: '',
       hideFalseStates: false
   }
   ```
2. Use a function *declaration* rather than function *expression*, since those are hoisted (they get evaluated before the step-by-step evaluation of the code):

   ```
   const todos = getSavedTodos()

   const filters={
       search: '',
       hideFalseStates: false
   }

   function getSavedTodos(){
       const todoJSON=localStorage.getItem('todo')
       if(todoJSON!==null)
       {
           return JSON.parse(todoJSON)
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function before the variable which references it.

```
const filters = {
    search: '',
    hideFalseStates: false
}

const getSavedTodos = function() {
    const todoJSON = localStorage.getItem('todo')
    if(todoJSON!==null) {
        return JSON.parse(todoJSON)
    }
}

const todos = getSavedTodos()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call a function that is defined later only if you use the `function` declaration...

```
foo(); // works
function foo() {
    console.log("Hey");
}
```

if instead you assign the function to a variable then the binding is a normal assignment and you can call it only after the assignment has been executed:

```
bar(); // Doesn't work, move after to get it working
var bar = function() {
    console.log("Hey");
};
```